# Angular-ui-router Unable to find a suitable version for angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, steroids

Typing $ `bower install angular-ui-router`, I get the following:

```
Unable to find a suitable version for angular, please choose one:
    1) angular#1.0.7 which resolved to 1.0.7 and has mySteroidsProject as dependants
    2) angular#* which resolved to 1.2.13 and has restangular#1.0.7 as dependants
    3) angular#>= 1.0.8 which resolved to 1.2.14-build.2338+sha.27873ac and has angular-ui-router#0.2.8 as dependants
Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json
[?] Answer:
```

While I am happy that bower takes care of these dependencies for me, I am at  aloss of what to do when a conflict occurs.  With a newly started project (within the past week), what differentiates these choices?

I am using steroids, which also has phonegap,

Comment: I can't find any documentation on steroids Angular generator (assuming that's what you used), I wonder why it's got 1.0.7 as dependency... you'd definitely want to use option #3 for ui-router `0.2.8`... but I'm not sure if that will break anything in `steroids`. You might consider giving ionicframework a chance... it uses the latest Angular.

Comment: Given that there is an issue, do you think I should persist it to bower with `!3` or just `3` and wait for bower to figure out an update down the road?

Comment: I'd test it first, if it works, then persist it.